# Trouble With CPAN Module

Tags: perl, www-mechanize, scraper

I've tried to install the WWW::Mechanize module with

```
'cpan WWW::Mechanize'
```

I get no errors on the 'use WWW::Mechanize' line which means its finding the files, but upon trying to instantiate it with:

```
$m = WWW::Mechanize->new();
```

I get the following problem:

Can't locate HTTP/Config.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/Updates/5.10.0/darwin-    thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.10.0 /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0 /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.10.0 /Network/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.10.0 /Network/Library/Perl /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0 .) at      /Library/Perl/5.10.0/LWP/UserAgent.pm line 746.

I'm not exactly sure what is going on.  I feel like I have all the neccessary dependencies, but I can't seem to find what this particular error means.

My script is empty besides the previously mentioned lines and

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Has anyone run into this?

Comment: "Can't locate HTTP/Config.pm" - looks like a missing dep to me...

Comment: It means that you do NOT have all of the necessary dependencies :-) You are missing the HTTP::Config module.

Comment: @tadmc Thanks so much.  I thought cpanm got all the necessary dependencies, but maybe something went wrong.  A quick run of 'cpan HTTP::Config' got everything up and running.  Just checked my tables and the POST went through!

Answer (score 7):

try installing it with the following command (from the shell):

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install WWW::Mechanize'
```

follow the installation process, and answer 'Y' where needed.